# Ubuntu 15 xRDP from Windows XP - breaks connection

Tags: windows-xp, xrdp

I installed Ubuntu 15 and made the steps described here:

[XRDP – Installing XRDP on Ubuntu 15.04](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=7984)

then I was able to connect and use remote desktop from Windows XP

using usual "Remote desktop connection"

but

it works only about for 2 minutes

then it breaks

and does not work again

until I restart Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

I tried Windows 8, the same problem.

Comment: It is because of NetGear,Inc. WNA1000M USB Wi-Fi, it works for some time then stops but continues to show good reception levels. It works good with windows 8. In Ubuntu the driver is rtl8192cu  4.2.0-16-generic